# Scrollable display of multiple video icons

Tags: javascript, videodisplay

I want to have multiple video icons at the top my website's front page. I will have about 20 or so which won't fit on one line (I want to keep the videos on one like) so I thought of having two button on the right of the group and on the left of the group where you click to scroll and view more videos. Do you know an easy way to do this? I can pass in the video links from the server in different Divs or anyway that will make it easy. I thought of using AJAX and pass it different set every time from the server with every click (I'm using Rails and it's fairly easy to do it) but that will be an extra load on the server which I'm trying to avoid. I'd rather send all the icons at once and let the JavaScript handle the scrolling.

I thought of using iFrame but I don't like the idea of scrollbar and wanted to be more like button

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). There is myriad of plugins that do exactly what you want. [Here is one](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html)